# How to access remote DynamoDB endpoint from application/code?

Tags: java, scala, http, server, amazon-dynamodb

In plain English, what I want to be able to do is create an endpoint in my application code that I can use to interact with the DynamoDB table on the remote server. I'd like to query and write to a persistent database on this server, and use the SDK to do so. Is creating HTTP service requests the only way of doing this?

I'm as interested in describing my problems as I am getting them solved, so if there is something unclear or an incorrect assumption underlying the question, or just anyway I can refine it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing up a few things are here. [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is a fully managed cloud database service, so you don't have your own database "server".

Comment: Good there's a start. By server, I probably was referring to the cloud.